# use separation of variables to solve differential wave equation with force term and steady state solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Consider the problem of a string held at both ends and acted on by gravity. Take the coordinate x to be along the string with the ends of the string at x = 0 and x = L. Take t as time and the variable u(x, t) as the vertical position of the string. The equation governing the string motion is the wave equation

$$
\frac{∂^2u}{∂t^2} = \frac{c^2∂^2u}{∂x^2}+G
$$

0 ≤ x ≤ L, t > 0

where G is a constant due to gravity and c is the constant wave speed. The ends of the string are held at different heights so that the boundary conditions are:

u(0,t)=0, t>0
u(L,t)=H, t>0

and the string is initially held completely flat and stationary:

u(x,0)=0, 0<x<L
$$
\frac{∂u(x,0)}{∂t}0 , 0<x<L 
$$

(a) The steady-state solution u(x, t) = w(x) as t → ∞ is found by setting
$ \frac{∂^2u}{∂t^2}= 0.$

Now consider u(x, t) = φ(x, t) + w(x). Obtain a homogenous wave-equation for φ with homogenous boundary conditions derived from the problem for u. Similarly, derive initial conditions for φ: one of these should be non-zero! Use separation of variables to find the solution for φ, and hence u.

for (a) I found $w(x) = \frac{Hx}{L}-G\frac{x(x-L)}{2c^2}$
but for (b) I'm not sure what it means for find a homogenous solution for φ. Does this mean I set u(x, t)=φ(x, t) , and w(x)=0 ? Not really sure what the question means.

Comment: you might want to delete the [5 MARKS] bit or someone might think you are getting other people to do your test for you. No homogeneous solution is mentioned, just a homogeneous equation and homogeneous boundary conditions - you can look those up as easily as anyone else?

Comment: but w(L) = HL/L -GL(L-L)/2c^2 = H , doesn't this satisfy u(L,t)=H for the steady state solution u(L,t)=w(x) ?

Comment: yeah I get those conditions. using them I end up with $ -w(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} C_nsin(\frac{nx\pi}{L}) $ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nc\pi}{L}D_nsin(\frac{nx\pi}{L}) $ evaluating the first Fourier series I get $C_n = \frac{2H}{n\pi}(-1^n)